# Xcode swift - cannot invoke 'pathForResource' with an argument list of type '(String!)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, error-handling

Please help me fix my code as I have the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'pathForResource' with an argument list of type '(String!)'

The error is on this line of code:

```
let urlpathString:String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(url)
```

My full code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let avPlayerViewControler = AVPlayerViewController()
    var avPlayer:AVPlayer?
    var videoNumber:Int!
    var url:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     
    }

    func playVideo() {
        switch videoNumber {
            case 1 : url="20"
            case 2 : url="10"
            default : break

            let urlpathString:String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(url)

            if let urlPath = urlpathString {
                let movieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)
                self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
                self.avPlayerViewControler.player = self.avPlayer

            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton){
        videoNumber=1
        playVideo()
    }

    @IBAction func Button2(sender: UIButton) {
        videoNumber=2
        playVideo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple `pathForResource` method of `NSBundle`, there's at least a second parameter e.g. `pathForResource:ofType:`

Since you need an `NSURL` anyway, use the URL released API, replace the entire `if let` expression with

```
func playVideo() {
  switch videoNumber {
    case 1 : url="20"
    case 2 : url="10"
    default : break
  }

  if let movieUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(url, withExtension: "mp4") {
     self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
     self.avPlayerViewControler.player = self.avPlayer
  }
}
```

You have to change `mp4` to the expected extension.

Comment: Hi There! Thanks for this! I have replaced the entire if let expression with you code. But I am still getting the Error. Please help

Comment: The same error is impossible since a different API is used. Of course you have to delete the line `let urlpathString:String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(url)`, too

Comment: I have replaced the code and no longer getting an error. But the video does not play on button click. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: It does say Code after 'break' will never be executed for  if let movieUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(url, withExtension: "mp4") { Could this be why?